# For Loop Creating Too Many Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

In my array of objects, each person has a set of information with an image. All of this information is inside of a div called imagebox. Now I want to add a button for each person in the array. Currently my code is creating multiple buttons instead of one per each object in my array. I attached an image to show what the page currently looks like. Like my image shows I have buttons outside the white div and also multiple. I just want one button inside of that white div per person, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with my for loop.

Here is my image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufxay.png)

HTML

```
<body onload="printBtn();">
    <div id="selectmenu">
        <select id="gender" onchange="checkGender()">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="search">    

    <div id="imagescontainer"></div>
    <div id="text"></div>
    <div id="imagebox"></div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var people = [

         {
        title: "davisss1",
        name: "Jeslyn Davis",
        gender: "male",
        age: 25,
        profileDescription: "I recently moved from New York, I'm looking forward to meeting new people.",
        status: "Single",
        hasKids: "No",
        wantsKids: "No",
        religion: "Prefer not to say",
        typeOfRelationship: "Long-term",
        city: "Kansas City",
        state: "Missouri",
        favSport: "softball",
        favDrink: "coke",
        favIceCream: "cookies-n-cream",
        favFood: "gelato",
        favMusic: "pop",
        imgs: "images/jeslyn.jpeg"
    },
    {
        title: "chlogib",
        name: "Chloe Gibbs",
        gender: "female",
        age: 24,
        profileDescription: "I'm currently running my own bakery so if you're every in town and want to get a bite let me know. I also work part time ",
        status: "Single",
        hasKids: "No",
        wantsKids: "Yes",
        religion: "Nonreligious",
        typeOfRelationship: "Long-term",
        city: "Louisville",
        state: "Kentucky",
        favSport: "volleyball",
        favDrink: "ice-tea",
        favIceCream: "mango",
        favFood: "cookies",
        favMusic: "rock",
        imgs: "images/chloe.jpeg"
    }
        ]

function checkGender() {

    var genderSelected = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var allimages = document.getElementById("imagescontainer");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");

    allimages.innerHTML = "";
    text.innerHTML = "";

    if (genderSelected == "male") {
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            if (people[i].gender == "male") {
                var content = `<div id="imagebox">` + `<img src="` + people[i].imgs + `" id="allimages"/>` + `<div id="text">` + `Title: ` + people[i].title + `<br\>` + `Name: ` + people[i].name + `<br\>` + `Age: ` + people[i].age + `<br\>` + `Description: ` + people[i].profileDescription + `<br\>` + `Status: ` + people[i].status + `<br\>` + `Has kids: ` + people[i].hasKids + `<br\>` + `Want kids: ` + people[i].wantsKids + `<br\>` + `Religion: ` + people[i].religion + `<br\>` + `Type of relationship: ` + people[i].typeOfRelationship + `<br\>` + `City: ` + people[i].city + `<br\>` + `State:` + people[i].state + `<br\>` + `Favorite sport: ` + people[i].favSport + `<br\>` + `Favorite drink: ` + people[i].favDrink + `<br\>` + `Favorite ice-cream flavor: ` + people[i].favIceCream + `<br\>` + `Favorite food: ` + people[i].favFood + `<br\>` + `Favorite music: ` + people[i].favMusic + `<br\>` + `</div>` + `</div>`;
                allimages.innerHTML += content;
                text.innerHTML += content;          

                 function createButtons() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
                        document.getElementById("imagebox").innerHTML += "<button>" + people[i] + "</button>";
                    }
                }
                createButtons();    
            }                     
        }        

    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            if (people[i].gender == "female") {

                var content = `<div id="imagebox">` + `<img src="` + people[i].imgs + `"id="allimages"/>` + `<div id="text">` + `Title: ` + people[i].title + `<br\>` + `Name: ` + people[i].name + `<br\>` + `Age: ` + people[i].age + `<br\>` + `Description: ` + people[i].profileDescription + `<br\>` + `Status: ` + people[i].status + `<br\>` + `Has kids: ` + people[i].hasKids + `<br\>` + `Want kids: ` + people[i].wantsKids + `<br\>` + `Religion: ` + people[i].religion + `<br\>` + `Type of relationship: ` + people[i].typeOfRelationship + `<br\>` + `City: ` + people[i].city + `<br\>` + `State:` + people[i].state + `<br\>` + `Favorite sport: ` + people[i].favSport + `<br\>` + `Favorite drink: ` + people[i].favDrink + `<br\>` + `Favorite ice-cream flavor: ` + people[i].favIceCream + `<br\>` + `Favorite food: ` + people[i].favFood + `<br\>` + `Favorite music: ` + people[i].favMusic + `<br\>` + `</div>` + `</div>`;
                allimages.innerHTML += content;
                text.innerHTML += content;
 function createButtons() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
                        document.getElementById("imagebox").innerHTML += "<button>" + people[i] + "</button>";
                    }
                }
                createButtons();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a working fiddle of the code? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @arximughal I was going to do that but I can't put my images in jsfiddle can I? I don't think there is a way for me to add my own in the fiddle that's why I have just posted the code here.

Comment: you can use a placeholder image https://placeholder.com/

Comment: @arximughal is the code visible? Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/heyitsme/b5ac1xph/4/

Comment: @arximughal Are the images visible? I tried putting image links instead of the ones I previously had.

Comment: That's fine. You don't need images. I got the idea.

Comment: First thing, you should not have the same ID for multiple elements on the same page. If you want the same selector for multiple elements, you should always use class.

Comment: Which ID was repeated? @arximughal

Comment: `imagebox` is inside the for loop.

Comment: I have used imagebox their because I want the button to be in that imagebox div. For each person I'm trying to have a button in the white box so in the loop I was trying to specify that I want the button to be added in the imagebox div. @arximughal

Comment: Yes. For that purpose, you should've done what I did in my example. Create a separate ID for each person's main div to target later in that same loop. Check my answer, it has a working codepen too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want the buttons to do, so I've just added the name of the person as the text for now.

**I've added a codepen**
https://codepen.io/benwritescode/pen/BaNwoXB

HTML
I did away with the multiple divs, they seemed superfluous to your requirements.

```
<html>
<head><!-- RE-ADD YOUR CSS&JS REFS --></head>
<body>
    <div id="selectmenu">
        <select id="gender" onchange="checkGender()">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="search">    

    <div id="people"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS
I've explained what's going on in the comments of the JS.

```
let people = [
        {
            title: "davisss1",
            name: "Jeslyn Davis",
            gender: "male",
            age: 25,
            profileDescription: "I recently moved from New York, I'm looking forward to meeting new people.",
            status: "Single",
            hasKids: "No",
            wantsKids: "No",
            religion: "Prefer not to say",
            typeOfRelationship: "Long-term",
            city: "Kansas City",
            state: "Missouri",
            favSport: "softball",
            favDrink: "coke",
            favIceCream: "cookies-n-cream",
            favFood: "gelato",
            favMusic: "pop",
            imgs: "images/jeslyn.jpeg"
        },
        {
            title: "chlogib",
            name: "Chloe Gibbs",
            gender: "female",
            age: 24,
            profileDescription: "I'm currently running my own bakery so if you're every in town and want to get a bite let me know. I also work part time ",
            status: "Single",
            hasKids: "No",
            wantsKids: "Yes",
            religion: "Nonreligious",
            typeOfRelationship: "Long-term",
            city: "Louisville",
            state: "Kentucky",
            favSport: "volleyball",
            favDrink: "ice-tea",
            favIceCream: "mango",
            favFood: "cookies",
            favMusic: "rock",
            imgs: "images/chloe.jpeg"
        }
    ];

// This is the HTML template which will be used for each person.
const PERSONTEMPLATE = `
<div class="imagebox">
    <img src="[[IMAGE]]" image="images" />
    <div class="text">
        Title: [[TITLE]]<br>
        Name: [[NAME]]<br>
        Age: [[AGE]]<br>
        Description: [[DESCRIPTION]]<br>
        Status: [[STATUS]]<br>
        Has kids: [[HASKIDS]]<br>
        Want kids: [[WANTSKIDS]]<br>
        Religion: [[RELIGION]]<br>
        Type of relationship: [[LOOKINGFOR]]<br>
        City:[[CITY]]<br>
        State:[[STATE]]<br>
        Favorite sport: [[FAVSPORT]]<br>
        Favorite drink: [[FAVDRINK]]<br>

        Favorite ice-cream flavor: [[FAVICECREAM]]<br>
        Favorite food: [[FAVFOOD]]<br>
        Favorite music: [[FAVMUSIC]]<br>
    </div>
    <button>[[BUTTONTEXT]]</button>
</div>`;    

// Fired on-change
function checkGender() {

    // Get the selected gender
    let genderSelected = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    // get the div to add the html to.
    let peopleDiv = document.getElementById("people");

    // Create a variable to which each appropriately gendered persons' HTML will be added to.
    let htmlToBuild = '';

    // Get the people by the selected gender using filter(), then use forEach to loop through each person in the returned array.
    people
        .filter(person => person.gender == genderSelected)
        .forEach(function(person) {

            // Gets the template and replaces the placeholder snippets.
            // += appends to a string.
            htmlToBuild += PERSONTEMPLATE
                            .replace('[[IMAGE]]',person.imgs)
                            .replace('[[TITLE]]',person.title)
                            .replace('[[NAME]]',person.name)
                            .replace('[[AGE]]',person.age)
                            .replace('[[DESCRIPTION]]',person.profileDescription)
                            .replace('[[STATUS]]',person.status)
                            .replace('[[HASKIDS]]',person.hasKids)
                            .replace('[[WANTSKIDS]]',person.wantsKids)
                            .replace('[[RELIGION]]',person.religion)
                            .replace('[[LOOKINGFOR]]',person.typeOfRelationship)
                            .replace('[[CITY]]',person.city)
                            .replace('[[STATE]]',person.state)
                            .replace('[[FAVSPORT]]',person.favSport)
                            .replace('[[FAVDRINK]]',person.favDrink)
                            .replace('[[FAVICECREAM]]',person.favIceCream)
                            .replace('[[FAVFOOD]]',person.favFood)
                            .replace('[[FAVMUSIC]]',person.favMusic)
                            .replace('[[BUTTONTEXT]]',person.name);
        });

    // Add the new HTML to the div.
    peopleDiv.innerHTML = htmlToBuild;

}
```

The code here has a good separation of concerns and is readable. You can update your HTML template independently of replacing any values within it. There are no duplicate pieces of code (male + female for loops), just one array filter and one foreach.

Comment: I'm really confused for this code. Why do you need to replace anything? I have all of those divs because I need to style the page as well. I also don't understand what the template is for. @BenjaminJamesKippax

Comment: @charmy You don't need them. You can apply your styling to each persons' individual divs using the classes. The template replaces the '<div>' +REALLY+'</div>'+'<div>' +HARD+'</div>'+'<div>' +TO+'</div>' +'<div>'+READ+'</div>'+'<div>' +CODE+'</div>' in your for loop ... means it's more readable.

Comment: The two that I had before were exactly what I was looking for but when I add more nothing shows up.

Comment: @charmy Can you fork the codepen I wrote and add more objects into the people array and provide the codepen link back here so I can see an example of the array?

Comment: I haven't used CodePen before so just clarifying, I forked the one you wrote and added more can you see them now? https://codepen.io/charmy-patel/pen/YzXrqZW @BenjaminJamesKippax

Comment: @charmy I don't think you saved it, here's an example I chucked together. https://codepen.io/benwritescode/pen/GRJMZEW

Comment: thank you so much got it. Is there a specific name for this concept you came up with using "templates"? This made it 10x easier then before, definitely will use this again.

Comment: @charmy No worries at all. Glad we got there in the end. There's a concept called Template Literals, which is similar. But in general this is just refactoring re-used code and ensuring your code has a separation of concerns. A couple of helpful concepts to look-up: single responsibility principle, dry programming.

Comment: @charmy in general, if you have code which is repeated and very similar. Like the same for loop but for different genders in this case, you should look to refactor that into it's own function or if it's a variable/object elevating its scope.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored some of the JavaScript code. Here's the updated code.

```
if (genderSelected == "male") {
      for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
          if (people[i].gender == "male") {
              var content = `<div id="imagebox` + i + `">` + `<img src="` + people[i].imgs + `" id="allimages"/>` + `<div id="text">` + `Title: ` + people[i].title + `<br\>` + `Name: ` + people[i].name + `<br\>` + `Age: ` + people[i].age + `<br\>` + `Description: ` + people[i].profileDescription + `<br\>` + `Status: ` + people[i].status + `<br\>` + `Has kids: ` + people[i].hasKids + `<br\>` + `Want kids: ` + people[i].wantsKids + `<br\>` + `Religion: ` + people[i].religion + `<br\>` + `Type of relationship: ` + people[i].typeOfRelationship + `<br\>` + `City: ` + people[i].city + `<br\>` + `State:` + people[i].state + `<br\>` + `Favorite sport: ` + people[i].favSport + `<br\>` + `Favorite drink: ` + people[i].favDrink + `<br\>` + `Favorite ice-cream flavor: ` + people[i].favIceCream + `<br\>` + `Favorite food: ` + people[i].favFood + `<br\>` + `Favorite music: ` + people[i].favMusic + `<br\>` + `</div>` + `</div>`;
              allimages.innerHTML += content;
              text.innerHTML += content;
              document.getElementById("imagebox" + i).innerHTML += "<button>" + people[i] + "</button>";
          }
      }

  } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
          if (people[i].gender == "female") {
              var content = `<div id="imagebox` + i + `">` + `<img src="` + people[i].imgs + `"id="allimages"/>` + `<div id="text">` + `Title: ` + people[i].title + `<br\>` + `Name: ` + people[i].name + `<br\>` + `Age: ` + people[i].age + `<br\>` + `Description: ` + people[i].profileDescription + `<br\>` + `Status: ` + people[i].status + `<br\>` + `Has kids: ` + people[i].hasKids + `<br\>` + `Want kids: ` + people[i].wantsKids + `<br\>` + `Religion: ` + people[i].religion + `<br\>` + `Type of relationship: ` + people[i].typeOfRelationship + `<br\>` + `City: ` + people[i].city + `<br\>` + `State:` + people[i].state + `<br\>` + `Favorite sport: ` + people[i].favSport + `<br\>` + `Favorite drink: ` + people[i].favDrink + `<br\>` + `Favorite ice-cream flavor: ` + people[i].favIceCream + `<br\>` + `Favorite food: ` + people[i].favFood + `<br\>` + `Favorite music: ` + people[i].favMusic + `<br\>` + `</div>` + `</div>`;
              allimages.innerHTML += content;
              text.innerHTML += content;
              document.getElementById("imagebox" + i).innerHTML += "<button>" + people[i] + "</button>";
          }
      }
  }
```

The main problem with your approach here was that you were printing buttons inside a `for` loop inside the `for` loop. First loop prints out the main `div` that contains the information related to a specific person. The second loop, that was being used for printing button, was inside the first loop.

Furthermore, because the `imagebox` ID was repeated on the page, `document.getElementById("imagebox")` was selecting the first ID and was printing the buttons inside the first div.

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/arximughal/pen/RwPLrGm

Comment: I added the button label too. Right now it's just the person's name. You can change that too whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you the buttons work now but what I'm confused about is what did you change for my div's because when I link my stylesheet now the images are in the center with the button on the far left. All of my styling that I had for imagebox is gone the info with img is no longer in the white divs I had. Also I don't understand what this <div id="imagebox + i + "> & document.getElementById("imagebox" + i) line of code are exactly doing. @arximughal

Comment: @charmy change your button selector from #imagebox to [id*="imagebox"]

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax Sorry, I don't understand which line of code you are referring to, I don't see #imagebox in my HTML or Javascript.

Comment: @charmy in your CSS, you should have a selector for the buttons, right? That selector will probably have #imagebox button {yourcss} or something similar? Change it to [id*="imagebox"] button {yourcss}

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax in my HTML the div has an id like so:  <div id="imagebox"></div>, so in my CSS I have #imagebox. I still confused on why that should be changed to [id*="imagebox"]. For the button yes I have styling but all I have is button{ margin:10px;}. I'm still unsure of which part you're referring to. Yes in the CSS but why change it to  [id*="imagebox"]? I haven't see it written like that before.

Comment: @charmy in the response you marked as the answer the IDs have changed to imagebox + i, so imagebox0, imagebox1, etc. Since element IDs must be unique. <div id="imagebox` + i + `">. The [id*="imagebox"] means, "All elements where the id CONTAINS imagebox", so this will cover all of the buttons.

Comment: Right but what I don't understand is does that mean I need to style each persons imagebox? Now the page doesn't have the info in the imagebox div the info the page has the img then info under and button on left. I wanted to keep the styling like my img posted above all the imgs, info and button within the white div. @BenjaminJamesKippax

Comment: @charmy You're asking me to put together a puzzle I don't have all the pieces for. I can't see the updated code, nor the output for it. If the response above doesn't fix your issue then this question shouldn't be marked as the answer. Using the [id*="imagebox"] selector will target the buttons in the same way #imagebox did before. I didn't write the code in this answer (I personally don't like it, since the same logic is repeated twice, among other things).

Comment: @arximughal Could you please explain what has changed in my styling I'm really confused now. I wanted the info img and button contained in the div like I previously had in the img shared in the question.

Comment: @charmy you should add a class to the `imagebox` div and the styles that you are applyging on the `#imagebox` selector, change the selector to `.imagebox` and then you should be able to get all your styles back.

Comment: @charmy I didn't edit any styles in the code. In fact, there were not styles available because you were using external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting double the number of buttons that you should have with the above code?

```
    if (genderSelected == "male") {
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            if (people[i].gender == "male") {//Here you are checking to ensure you get only males
                var content = `<div id="imagebox">` + `<img src="` + people[i].imgs + `" id="allimages"/>` + `<div id="text">` + `Title: ` + people[i].title + `<br\>` + `Name: ` + people[i].name + `<br\>` + `Age: ` + people[i].age + `<br\>` + `Description: ` + people[i].profileDescription + `<br\>` + `Status: ` + people[i].status + `<br\>` + `Has kids: ` + people[i].hasKids + `<br\>` + `Want kids: ` + people[i].wantsKids + `<br\>` + `Religion: ` + people[i].religion + `<br\>` + `Type of relationship: ` + people[i].typeOfRelationship + `<br\>` + `City: ` + people[i].city + `<br\>` + `State:` + people[i].state + `<br\>` + `Favorite sport: ` + people[i].favSport + `<br\>` + `Favorite drink: ` + people[i].favDrink + `<br\>` + `Favorite ice-cream flavor: ` + people[i].favIceCream + `<br\>` + `Favorite food: ` + people[i].favFood + `<br\>` + `Favorite music: ` + people[i].favMusic + `<br\>` + `</div>` + `</div>`;
                allimages.innerHTML += content;
                text.innerHTML += content;          

                 function createButtons() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {//this creates a button for each person, regardless of gender
                        document.getElementById("imagebox").innerHTML += "<button>" + people[i] + "</button>";
                    }
                }
                createButtons(); //you are creating a button for each person here, regardless of gender(although you should be checking to see if the gender is correct)

            }
```

Comment: Please check my answer, you'll see that I create a separate ID for each person rendered based on the loop index (not the most efficient way, but it will give you an idea how to implement it) and then targeted the new ID to add the button inside the div.